# How to split and remove empty spaces before get the result

Tags: scala, split

I have this `String`:

```
val str = "9617 / 20634"
```

So after split i want to parse only the 2 values `9617 & 20634` in order to calculate percentage.
So instead of `trim` after the split can i do it before ?

Comment: have you tried? just open the REPL and give it a try

Comment: `.split(" */ *")` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easier to remove spaces after the split than before. Unless you are expected to trim it before, here is a simpler way of doing it.

```
val Array(x, y) = "9617 / 20634".split("/").map(_.trim.toFloat)
val p = x / y * 100
```

Values are converted to `Float` to prevent integer division leading to 0. 
The `val Array(x,y) = ...` statement is just another way of calling 
[unapplySeq](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.6.0/scala/Array$object.html#unapplySeq%28Array%5BA%5D%29) of the Array object.

Answer (score -1):

For scalable solution one might use regexps:

```
scala> val r = """(\d+) */ *(\d+)""".r
r: scala.util.matching.Regex = (\d+) +/ +(\d+)

scala> "111      / 222" match { 
  case r(a, b) => println(s"Got $a, $b")
  case _ =>  
}
Got 111, 222
```

This is useful if you need different usage patterns.

Here you define correspondence between variables from you input (`111`, `222`) and match groups (`(\d+)`, `(\d+)`).

Comment: You miss `"111/222"`

Comment: That's what I wanted to do. If user, for example, might have spaces on the left of /, but not on the right, all he need to do is to modify regex, + to *. For different use cases different modification might be needed. That's why I called "scalable" solution.

Comment: Modified answer with * instead of + for spaces.